# How to use jquery keyup event on an element that was injected after the document ready

Tags: javascript, onkeyup

i have this code

```
<div class="form-group col-md-3">
<label for="exampleInputEmail1" class="col-md-12 texto_value">valor</label>
<div class="form-group col-md-6">
    <input type="text" class="form-control" value="valor" disabled>
</div>
<div class="form-group col-md-6">
    <input type="hidden" name="name_jacket[]" value="valor">
    <input type="number" class="form-control" name="jacket_value[]" 
      id="valor" step="any" placeholder="valor">
</div>
</div>
```

This div is ijected by js with the function:

```
('#select_type').on('change', function(e){
```

but i need to create a keyup event on input name="jacket_value[]" but the keyup event doesn't work.

How can i make it works.

Comment: Use event delegation instead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change your Javascript code like this.

```
    $(document).on('change', "input[type='number'][name='jacket_value[]']", function(data) {
        var btn = this;
        console.log(this.value);
    });
```

In this case you don't need to wait for the DOM to be ready `$(document.ready() is not required.` You can simply use above code and it will work.

Answer (score 0):

('#select_type').on('keyup', function(e){

Answer (score 0):

Would you please try following way, It seems working fine.

```js
$("input[type='number'][name='jacket_value[]']").on('keyup', function(e){
 console.log(this.value);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="form-group col-md-3">
<label for="exampleInputEmail1" class="col-md-12 texto_value">valor</label>
<div class="form-group col-md-6">
    <input type="text" class="form-control" value="valor" disabled>
</div>
<br>
<div class="form-group col-md-6">
    <input type="hidden" name="name_jacket[]" value="valor">
    <input type="number" class="form-control" name="jacket_value[]" 
      id="valor" step="any" placeholder="valor">
</div>
</div>
```